# Regex doesn't capture results accurately in C# but works fine on online regex tools

Tags: c#, regex

This regex - `(.*).ap(.\d*)$` - works fine in online regex tools (for example, works [here](http://regexr.com/3f22u)) but not in C#.

The intent is that for a string that ends with `.ap<some numbner>` (`.ap` followed by some number - .ap1, .ap123 etc), we want to capture everything on the left of the last `.ap` and everything on the right of the last `.ap`. For example for `abcfile.csv.ap123`, we want to capture `abcfile.csv` and `123`.

`(.*).ap(.\d*)$` captures the two groups as expected in online tools but in C#, it captures the entire name (captures abcfile.csv.ap123, in the above example).

The C# code is -

```
string renameSuffix = "ap";
Match match = Regex.Match(filename, @"(.*)\." + renameSuffix + @"(\d*)$");
```

match.Success is true but match.Captures.Count is 1 and match.Captures[0].Value contains the entire filename (I'm looking at this in a watch).

What could be wrong here?

More examples -

- TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D.csv - Shouldn't match
- TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D_A.csv.ap123 - Should match and capture TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D_A.csv and 123
- TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D_A.csv.ap123.ds - Shouldn't match
- TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D.csv.ap2.ap1 - Should match and capture TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D.csv.ap2 and 1

Comment: Show the code you're using to view the matches, because depending on what properties you look at you get different answers..

Comment: @BugFinder It is match.Captures[0].Value in a watch window. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: You get two Groups here: `match.Groups[1].Value` and `match.Groups[2].Value` - they contain the captured texts.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I've run your pattern and I get for `abcfile.csv.ap123` 3 groups: `abcfile.csv.ap123`, `abcfile.csv` and `123`.

Comment: The regular expression is matching the whole string (eg in your online checker it is highlighting the entire string), but you want the groups within that capture so you must look in the `Groups` property as well. To understand why it isn't just the capture collection imagine an regular expression of just `\d+` applied to the string `123-456-789`. There are three captures that match the entire regular expression (123, 456, 789). In your example your regex matches the entire string or nothing so there is only ever one capture and then the groups inside that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine

[image]

just try `match.Groups[1]` and `match.Groups[2]`

In the 0 index you have full match and only subsequent groups relate to regex groups.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx for documentation (aimed at the question asker, not the answerer)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is working :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] filenames = { 
               "TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D.csv", // - Shouldn't match
               "TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D_A.csv.ap123", // - Should match and capture TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D_A.csv and 123
               "TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D_A.csv.ap123.ds", // - Shouldn't match
               "TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D.csv.ap2.ap1" //- Should match and capture TestCashFile_10_12-25-2016_D.csv.ap2 and 1
                             };

            string renameSuffix = "ap";
            string pattern = @"(?'filename'.*)\." + renameSuffix + @"(?'suffix'\d*)$";

            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(filename, pattern);
                Console.WriteLine("Match : {0}, Filename : {1}, Suffix : {2}", match.Success ? "True" : "False", match.Groups["filename"].Value, match.Groups["suffix"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```